# phpunit --repeat : how to know which step of repeat cycle you are in?

Tags: php, phpunit, repeat

I'm running `phpunit --repeat X` to track down inconsistent errors in an app.
I need to know which step of the repeat cycle I'm in : how do I get this?

I think it should be possible with `repeat()` from [src/TextUI/Arguments/Arguments.php](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/00e1cf3096833f1994fdbeb9f79570448bb1f80f/src/TextUI/Arguments/Arguments.php#L1300-L1307) but cannot manage to do it

Any clue? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you wrote a test which it's passed the first five times but failed on the 6th cycle, then there is a problem with the test. but I'm wondering knowing the cycle, how could help you with that?